# How do I add three lines to the middle of 447 html files after different search strings, on a freeBSD server?

Tags: html, perl

I need to add three lines to 447 pages of html.  Specifically I need to add the lines:

```
<input name="prev" type="button" value="prev" onClick="handlePrev()" id="prevButton">
<input name="next" type="button" value="next" onClick="handleNext()" id="nextButton">
<script src="nav.js"></script>
```

after the

```
</table>
```

tag.

I would prefer to do this in perl, but really any possible way would be OK. I would also be open to doing this in Windows, if that would be easier.

One of the scripts I've tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -i.bak -p
my $prevButton = '<input name="prev" type="button" value="prev" onClick="handlePrev()" id="prevButton">\n';
my $nextButton = '<input name="next" type="button" value="next" onClick="handleNext()" id="nextButton">\n';
my $jsInclude = '<script src="nav.js"></script>\n';
print "TEST" if /\<\/table\>/;
```

It touches the pages but doesn't replace the table tag with TEST as I would have expect.

FYI: I'm a total perl newbie, so I may be totally off here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -i.bak -p
my $prevButton = ...
my $nextButton = ...
my $jsInclude = ...
$_.="$prevButton\n$nextButton\n$jsInclude" if /\<\/table\>/;
```

and run the script as:

```
perl prg.pl /path/*.html
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i -e '/<table>/aYourStringToAppendHere' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
cat <<\! >append.txt
> <input name="prev" type="button" value="prev" onClick="handlePrev()" id="prevButton">
> <input name="next" type="button" value="next" onClick="handleNext()" id="nextButton">
> <script src="nav.js"></script>
> !
cat <<\! >file.txt
> a
> b
> c
> <table>
> x
> y
> z
> </table>
> d
> e
> f
> !
sed '/<\/table>/r append.txt' file.txt
a
b
c
<table>
x 
y
z
</table>
<input name="prev" type="button" value="prev" onClick="handlePrev()" id="prevButton">
<input name="next" type="button" value="next" onClick="handleNext()" id="nextButton">
<script src="nav.js"></script>
d
e
f
```

When all looks fine:

```
sed -i.bak '/<\/table>/r append.txt' <list of files>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Perl-Script that works. It adds your 3 lines in all files with a certain doctype in a directory. Enter the path to your directory and the doctype and give it a try:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $startdir = 'enter the path to your files here!';
my $find = '</table>';
my $replace = '</table><input name="prev" type="button" value="prev" onClick="handlePrev()" id="prevButton">
<input name="next" type="button" value="next" onClick="handleNext()" id="nextButton">
<script src="nav.js"></script>';

my $doctype = 'enter your doctype here!';


find(
sub{
  return unless (/\.$doctype$/i);
  local @ARGV = $_;
  local $^I = '.bac';

  while( <> ){
    if( s/$find/$replace/ig ) {
      print;
    }
    else {
      print;
    }
  }
}, $startdir);

print "done";
```